# manipular arquivo csv em c++

Tags: c++

Preciso ler uma arquivo cvs com os seguintes campos:

```
Id,OwnerUserId,CreationDate,Score,Title,Body    

Id    inteiro  
OwerUserID    inteiro  
Data     vou armazerna como char    
Score     inteiro  
Title      texto  
Body       texto
```

Exemplo de uma linha(sao muitas linhas) :

```
469, 147, 2008-08-02T15:11:16Z, 21, How can I find the full path to a font from its   display name on a Mac?, "Iam using the Photoshop's.......</ul> "
```

Esses..... no campo body foi para encurtar, pois o tamanho do texto e bem maior

e armazenar em uma vetor de structs do tipo:

```
struct Questions {

    int id;  
    int ownerUsedId;  
    char creationDate[30];  
    int score;
    char title[100];
    char body[200];

};
```

Para isso fiz a seguinte função:

```
void loadQuestions( fstream &file, Questions *questions)
{
    string registro;



    getline(file, registro);


    char *buffer =new char[500];
    char *ptr;

    getline(file, registro); 
    strcpy(buffer, registro.c_str());  



    ptr = strtok(buffer, ",");
       cout << atoi(ptr) << "   ";// pega o campo id

    ptr = strtok(NULL, ",");
       cout << atoi(ptr) << "    ";// pega o campo ownerUsedId

    ptr = strtok(NULL, ",");// pega o campo data
       cout << (ptr) << "    ";

    ptr = strtok(NULL, ",");// pega o campo score
       cout << atoi(ptr) << "    ";



} // mostrei na tela para ver se o programa tava certo, nao armazenei ainda na struct
```

Ate a quarta virgula deu tudo certo, estou separando por virgula, mas surge o problema: tanto no campo title ou body  pode aparecer uma virgula no meio de texto, forçando `strtok` para neste ponto , com isso bagunçado toda a leitura.

Pergunta : como armazenar cada campo corretamente na minha estruct, visto que no campo body e tittle pode aparecer varias virgulas, uma coisa que percebi foi que o campo Body começa e termina com aspas("") , ou seja poderia usar aspa como delimitara para copiar esse campo, mas dentro do campo body( que é um texto) pode haver aspas (" ")
Como possa copiar cada um desse campos corretamente?

Comment: Se o que pretende capturar for bastante especifico então começa a ser mais fácil utilizar uma regex. No seu caso em particular o mais simples será provavelmente trocar o `strotok` do title para apanhar `"` ao invés de `,`

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar uma abordagem composta. Até o quarto campo você usa o strtok, dali em diante você faz um `for` procurando pela primeira ocorrência de aspas (início do Body), tudo que juntou até ali é o Title e dali até o final é o Body.

Comment: o problema que, no campo title pode aparecer  uma aspa, sao 600000 linhas , com os mais variados texto no campo title

Comment: Você não havia falado de aspas no title também :) Você tem controle sobre a geração do arquivo?

Comment: esqueci de falar da possibilidade das aspas no title, nao tenho controle nao , esse  é um dataset  do site https://www.kaggle.com/stackoverflow/pythonquestions. é um arquivo com 600000 mil registros, ai nao consigo olhar um por um para ver se existe algumas aspas no campo title